# PHP-DI inject static classes

Tags: php, dependency-injection

I've started using [`PHP-DI`](http://php-di.org/doc/getting-started.html) to manage some dependency injection for a custom CMS. It's integrated with FastRoute that will manage the routing (I've started writing my own routing system but for now is too poor to be used in production). I need to inject an instance of RedBeanPHP that will use mainly static methods. After reading the docs, I can't achive the scope, is there any way to accomplish this task?

```
<?php 

require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

use \RedBeanPHP\R;

// Thi part of code is taken from the docs of FastRoute on github
$dispatcher = FastRoute\simpleDispatcher(function(FastRoute\RouteCollector $router) {
    $router->addRoute('GET', '/', 'Controller/index');
    /* User uri mapping */
    $router->addGroup('/user' , function(FastRoute\RouteCollector $router){
      $router->addRoute('GET', '/', 'UserController/index');
      $router->addRoute('POST', '/doRegistration', 'UserController/register');
    });
});

// Fetch method and URI from somewhere
$httpMethod = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

// Strip query string (?foo=bar) and decode URI
if(false !== $pos = strpos($uri, '?')){
    $uri = substr($uri, 0, $pos);
}
$uri = rawurldecode($uri);

$routeInfo = $dispatcher->dispatch($httpMethod, $uri);
switch ($routeInfo[0]) {
    case FastRoute\Dispatcher::NOT_FOUND:
        // ... 404 Not Found
        break;
    case FastRoute\Dispatcher::METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED:
        $allowedMethods = $routeInfo[1];
        // ... 405 Method Not Allowed
        break;
    case FastRoute\Dispatcher::FOUND:
        $handler = $routeInfo[1];
        $vars = $routeInfo[2];
        list($class, $method) = explode("/", $handler, 2);
        // dependency injection
        $container = new DI\Container();
        $redBean = $container->call('RedBeanPHP\R');
        $container->get($redBean);

        call_user_func_array([new $class, $method], $vars);
        break;
}
```

Comment: It's difficult to offer a solution when we have no idea how you are doing what you currently do.  If you add your current code which is causing the problem and any errors then this would help a lot.

Comment: @NigelRen question updated. Unfortunately I don't have the error message that was showed to post it, I can tell you that was relative about the fact that RedBeanPHP ORM use a static way to do all the operations.

Comment: You may better try [phpleage/route](https://route.thephpleague.com/) (based on fastroute) and [phpleage/container](https://github.com/thephpleague/container).

Comment: @odan why you suggest me this? I'm finding that FastRoute is working fine and PHP-DI for non static classes seems to work well. What are the differences?